# How do edit an entity (with AsNoTracking) after add

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

With the following code

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }


public class Index3Model : PageModel
{
    public Index3Model(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        MyDbContext = myDbContext;
    }

    public MyDbContext MyDbContext { get; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var p = new Personen();
        p.Name = "PersonName";
        p.Adresse = new Adressen() { Name = "AdressName" };
        MyDbContext.Personen.Add(p);
        MyDbContext.SaveChanges();

        // Do something ....

        var p1 = MyDbContext.Personen.Where(a => a.Name == "PersonName").Include(a => a.Adresse).First();
        p1.Name += "Test";
        p1.Adresse.Name += "Test";
        MyDbContext.Personen.Update(p1);
        MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

i get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Personen' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I think i understand the problem, but how can i resolve it?

**Edit:**
The second part of my code is in an other function, therefor i cant use "p" again:

```
public Index3Model(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        MyDbContext = myDbContext;
    }

    public MyDbContext MyDbContext { get; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var p = new Personen();
        p.Name = "PersonName";
        p.Adresse = new Adressen() { Name = "AdressName" };
        MyDbContext.Personen.Add(p);
        MyDbContext.SaveChanges();

        OtherFunction();
    }

    public void OtherFunction()
    {
        // Do something ....
        var p1 = MyDbContext.Personen.Where(a => a.Name == "PersonName").Include(a => a.Adresse).First();
        p1.Name += "Test";
        p1.Adresse.Name += "Test";
        MyDbContext.Personen.Update(p1);
        MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When i detach "p" after the Add method with

```
MyDbContext.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

the adress object is still in the context. I understand that it is possible to detatch the "Adress" object too, but i am looking for a general solution for this problem. I think in a little bit more complex scenarios, this error occurse very often.

**Edit 2:**
My problem is, that i dont want to pass "p" in this function, because i call the second function from many other places in my project and in this places i dont have a object "p".

And i think there are many other scenarios, where i dont know if a object or maybe a list of objects contains entities, which are in the context, but i dont know it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your method, you are adding the object "p" to the context by calling

```
MyDbContext.Personen.Add(p);
```

Your entity is now being tracked by the context, yet later in the method you are fetching the same object from the context and then readding it again by calling

```
MyDbContext.Personen.Update(p1);
```

All update does is that it readds the entity to the context and applies the Modified flag to it.
There's no need to call update on it because entity is still tracking the changes to the object.

Since you're doing everything in one method, you can just keep editing the "p" object instead of trying to readd it to the context again.

If you absolutely need to do it this way, you can detach an object from the entity tracker with

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Comment: I simplified my example, which I should not have done. I call the object in another function and therefore I have no access to the original one. If I detach the object, the address object is still in the context, which causes the same error.

Comment: You are calling the second method from the first one, nothing has really changed except code placement. The db context is still the same object and the p is still being tracked. The problem is the call to update which tries to readd the object. Remove the call and then save changes.

Comment: yes but i dont want to refer to p in the second method and the getall function doesnt return the object from the context.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use below code：

```
public void OnGet()
{
    var p = new Personen();
    p.Name = "PersonName";
    p.Adresse = new Adressen() { Name = "AdressName" };
    MyDbContext.Personen.Add(p);
    MyDbContext.SaveChanges();

    MyDbContext.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached;

    OtherFunction();
}

public void OtherFunction()
{
    // Do something ....
    var p1 = _context.Persons.Where(a => a.Name == "PersonName").Include(a => a.Address).First();
    p1.Name += "Test";
    p1.Adresse.Name += "Test";
    MyDbContext.Personen.Update(p1);
    MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: My problem is, that i dont want to pass "p", because i call the second function from many other places in my project and in this places i dont have a object "p"

Comment: @schini Ok,I understand.But it works well when I try your code with `context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;` in a new project.See my edit.Do you mean you also get the same error with above code?